# Uncaught ReferenceError: (variable) is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
  function modalAutoOpen() {
        if (@Model.ModalId != 0 && @Model.ViewTab == "Mine") {
            $('#myArrangements_' + @Model.ModalId).modal({
                show: true
            });
        }
```

There are no errors at first, but when I do something to change the 'ViewTab' to "Mine", in the chrome console I'm getting the error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Mine is not defined'.  My understanding of this would be that the variable is perhaps private in scope and it can't read it, but chrome displays this which shows it is picking up the value of the ViewTab':

```
function modalAutoOpen() {
        if (2 != 0 && Mine == "Mine") {
            $('#myArrangements_' + 2).modal({
                show: true
            });
        }
```

Comment: what does the variable `Mine` refer to? Should that viewtab name be in quotes perhaps to make it not actually be a variable?

Comment: Ah that's it!  I'm used to C# where its no problem to say if( x == "hello"){...    I didn't know that in javascript you have to say if("x" =="hello"){...

Comment: even in c# `x` would have to be a declared variable. In general though if you are hardcoding tests like `2!=0` which can't change then you might find it neater to use that conditional serverside to determine whether to output code or not. for example you could just omit the `2!=0 `check above and if the server side variable meant it was `0!=0` then you could just omit the entire block of code.

Comment: I think you misunderstood that the second function which was the output I got from chrome in the chrome console.  The first function is the one I'm using.  The variable @Model.Viewtab was passed from the controller to the view so it is previously declared.

Comment: I appreciate that. My point was (and it may be that it is not needed) is that the `Mine` without the quotes in the actual javascript (not your razor view) is akin to your `x` in c#. If it is a variable it needs to be declared beforehand like c#, if it is a string it needs to be quoted, again just like c#. You only need to say `if ("x"=="hello")` if you want to treat x as a literal string.

Answer (score -1):

I think that if you check before using the variable you don't see any errors:

```
 if(2 != 0 && typeof(Mine) === "object" && Mine == "Mine")
```